# Plone 4.0.2, TinyMCE selected internal link is not sticking

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone 4.0.2 site out of the box. I havent customized the theme so its pretty vanilla. I have pages in the site and a couple PDF documents. I have a problem that when I;

- edit a page via TinyMCE
- create some text,
- highlight that text
- choose "insert link"
- select the object I want to link to
- choose "insert"

The text I have selected is not blue or underlined. When I view the HTML the href is not there. This problem doesnt always occur but occurs most of the time. About 1 in 10 times the link will successfully stick. I cannot spot a pattern. Im not getting any obvious errors, Viewing the error_log doesn't reveal anything."Link using UID's" is turned ON.

Im at a bit of a loss not sure what else to try. I don't have the option of upgrading the site. Other versions of Plone that Ive tried do not have this problem.

Any thoughts or ideas?

thankyou,
Brian

Answer (score 3):

Is a bug of old TinyMCE with recent Chrome and Firebox browsers fixed in the official branch of Products.TinyMCE 1.2.x and Products.TinyMCE 1.1.x.

As nobody ever released additional releases you must use those development branch (in your case: 1.1.x).

https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/tree/1.1

Comment: It's also fixed in the 1.3.x branch of Products.TinyMCE :-) But this branch may not suitable for Plone 4.0.x.